# How to work without develop branch in jgitflow-mavenplugin

Tags: git, maven, jgitflow-maven-plugin

How to work without `develop` branch in `jgitflow-maven-plugin`?
We want to use the `master` branch as our common branch for continuous delivery, and sporadically do a "release" to deploy the solution. we don't use feature branch as we use feature-toggle instead. How should I configure jgitflow-maven-plugin for that need? By default it swaps the `master` branch with a so-called `develop` branch and assigns another meaning to the `master` branch: something like a snapshot of the last release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
<flowInitContext>
            <masterBranchName>master</masterBranchName>
            <developBranchName>master</developBranchName>
```

Comment: Thank you. I feared to get conflicts with this solution. I finally use `masterBranchName=tagged-release` and `developBranchName=master`, which is a similar solution.

Comment: WRONG!!! It doesn't work: you get the following error: `Error starting release: master and develop branches cannot be the same`.